# AWS Glue - How to query Glue catalog for LOCATION?

Tags: aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

Anybody know how (Athena w Glue) to return the full s3:// address of a table whose table name I know.  Something like:

```
SELECT location FOR TABLE xyz;
```

Seems simple enough but I can't find it

Comment: did you add partition metascore ? command like `MSCK REPAIR TABLE test;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also possible to get the location via `aws cli` command:

`aws glue get-table --database-name bigdata --name test --query "Table.StorageDescriptor.Location"`

output: 
**"s3://bucket_name/big_data/test/"**

Following gives all the details of a table.

`aws glue get-table --database-name bigdata --name test`

To get the location, access it via `Table.StorageDescriptor.Location`

Comment: Thanks @syadv  Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 6):

Found a way using boto3 (Python library for AWS)

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('glue')
tbl_data = client.get_table(DatabaseName='<database_name>', Name='xyz')

tbl_data['Table']['StorageDescriptor']['Location']
```

Comment: If you get an error on specifying the region, just add "region_name=<your region>" as a parameter of boto3.client